# insert into phpMyAdmin - loop array

Tags: php

sorry, im a beginner. Still learning the basics of php.
Here is where i'm stuck. I'm using php to get the results and sending the results onto the database(phpMyAdmin).

I've set up a loop to get the results

i'm trying to get the above results to be sent to phpMyAdmin. i cannot work out on how to do it. I guess i need INSERT INTO somewhere inside the loop so that it can send each into phpMyAdmin There are about 10 different questions. they are displayed on the php but do not know where to go ahead from here

thanks for your help :)

edit
Thanks for the guide, I cannot seem to work out where mysql_query will go inside the loop.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO.......

Comment: just below echo put insert statement also in the for loop but i am curious why u using for each because that we use in case of iterating through an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming u have connected to DB and has a proper table in the DB**.I am just modifying your code** so make sure about the value of `$_POST['something']` and the way it should behave.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname") or 
die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

if (isset($_POST['something'])) 
{ 
    foreach ($_POST['something'] as $key => $value) 
    { 
        echo 'something #' . $key . ' You gave it ' . $value . '<br>'; 
        $a="insert into tablename(columnname) values('$value')";
        $b=mysqli_query($con,$a);
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'no options selected'; 
}
```

Comment: I seem to be receiving this error...Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters. I have a table set up with two columns. 1 one somethingID and the other called optionID. thanks

Comment: you are getting the error because as the first argument of mysql_query u need to include the database connection variable,i updated my answer.

Comment: change the insert statement as per your need and requirement

Comment: so sorry, but now i'm getting a different error after making the relevant changes which you suggested . "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in...... "

Comment: i think you made some mistake in database connectivity.check that properly use mysql_error for that,which you can see now in my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a database, you need to use the PHP mysqli_* functions. You can find more informations on the PHP online manual.

You can also use PDO (PHP Data Objects). Here's the link to a very good tutorial : http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html

Both ways are valid and secure.

Comment: Do you think, your answer is anyway related to the question asked here?

Comment: @BhavikShah ya i think a tutorial will be a nice place to start from as the OP already said he is new to php